# WinUI3 C++ ListBox itemsSource

Tags: c++, winui-3

I found the C# source for WinUI3 ListBox itemsSource.
https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery.git

But There is no example for ListBox itemsSource in C++.

```
<ListBox Width="200">
    <x:String>Arial</x:String>
    <x:String>Comic Sans MS</x:String>
    <x:String>Courier New</x:String>
</ListBox>


<ListBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Fonts}" DisplayMemberPath="Item1" SelectedValuePath="Item2"/>
```

C#

```
private List<Tuple<string, FontFamily>> _fonts = new List<Tuple<string, FontFamily>>()
{
   new Tuple<string, FontFamily>("Arial", new FontFamily("Arial")),
   new Tuple<string, FontFamily>("Comic Sans MS", new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS")),
   new Tuple<string, FontFamily>("Courier New", new FontFamily("Courier New")),
   new Tuple<string, FontFamily>("Segoe UI", new FontFamily("Segoe UI")),
   new Tuple<string, FontFamily>("Times New Roman", new FontFamily("Times New Roman"))
};

public List<Tuple<string, FontFamily>> Fonts
{
   get { return _fonts; }
}
```

C++

```
?
```

Comment: AFAIK, WinRT doesn't have a Tuple type. It works with C# thanks to generation magic that happens behind the scene and this interface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.ixamltype (have a look at the `XamlTypeInfo.g.cs` you can find below `obj` directory). One solution is to author a WinRT component and bind it "normally" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis